# Compress gzip/Deflate string with golang

Tags: c#, go, compression, gzip, deflate

I can't correctly compress strings the same way I can in C#.

I have this line:

```
text:= "Stories often have a moral or message."
```

Am use C#:

```
public static byte[] Deflate(byte[] bArr)
{

    MemoryStream mm = new MemoryStream();
    using (ZlibStream zlib = new ZlibStream(mm, Ionic.Zlib.CompressionMode.Compress))
    {
        zlib.Write(bArr, 0, bArr.Length);
        zlib.Close();

    }
    return mm.ToArray();
}
```

C# result:
`eJwLLskvykwtVshPK0nNU8hILEtVSFTIzS9KzFHIL1LITS0uTkxP1QMAEwkN2g==`

But Golang Deflate Compress gives me this result:

`eJwKLskvykwtVshPK0nNU8hILEtVSFTIzS9KzFHIL1LITS0uTkxP1QMEAAD//xMJDdo=`

What is the problem and how can I compress in Golang the same way as in C#?

Comment: The golang output is as valid as the C# output. Just try to decompress. The same question here about ruby, but same cause: [Compressed output differs from Go to Ruby Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52767214/compressed-output-differs-from-go-to-ruby-implementation)

Comment: thanks for your reply. I understand that the results with decompression are the same. but the essence of the question is to recreate the function in golang. because the source server accepts exactly this version of compression

Comment: *"because the source server accepts exactly this version of compression"* - I don't understand this. The source server does not decompress the output but compares the compressed result? Sounds broken to me. Even with C# the results differ when changing the compression level.